# Can I install Ubuntu Server alongside Windows?

Tags: installation, windows, dual-boot, wubi

I am wondering if its possible to install ubuntu server side by side with windows, and I don't want it to touch it. Is possible, i know it is on the desktop version but not sure for the server. The version is the one currently downloaded as of today the July 4 2012

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop are different just because they have different packages installed by default. See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F) for explanation.

So, you can turn Desktop to Server or turn Server to Desktop whenever you want.

In your case, you should give one or several partitions for Ubuntu Server installation, and install the Ubuntu Server. The installer will detect other OS's on your computer and add entries for them automatically in GRUB2 boot loader.

Thus, you can boot into Windows or Ubuntu Server every time you power on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows-based Ubuntu Installer *(Wubi)* will *not* work with Ubuntu Server, but a traditional "dual-boot" installation -- which involves partitioning your hard disk appropriately -- will work just fine.